# Change tr background color when checkbox in td is checked

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a table row color changed when a checkbox inside a td is selected with css and avoid javascript to change dom.

This is what i have tried so far but it does not work

```
tr:has(> .check-pokayoke:checked)
```

Comment: You can do it using js or jQuery

Comment: I know that but i wanted to try doing with css

Comment: In the moment the has() selector is in working draft status and no browser supports it (https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has). You'll need JS (or have to to wait some years for better browser support ;)).

Comment: that's unfortunate